# configure build path in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

when I am putting the mouse pointer on the `Reservation reservation=restTemplate.getForObject("localhost:8082/flight_reservation/reservation/"+id, Reservation.class);`
line then it's telling configure build path.

```
package com.bulbul.flightcheekIn.integration;

import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import com.bulbul.flightcheckIn.integration.dto.Reservation;
import com.bulbul.flightcheckIn.integration.dto.ReservationUpdateRequest;

public class ReservationRestClientImpl implements ReservationRestClient {

    @Override
    public Reservation findReservation(Long id) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Reservation reservation = restTemplate.getForObject("localhost:8082/flight_reservation/reservation/"+id, Reservation.class);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Reservation updateReservation(ReservationUpdateRequest request) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a configuration class in Spring which uses builder pattern, like below.

@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

.....

```
@Bean
public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .rootUri("http://localhost:8082/flight_reservation/reservation/");
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.build();
}
```

}

Your Client class autowire rest template

public class ReservationRestClientImpl implements ReservationRestClient {

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Override
public Reservation findReservation(Long id) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Reservation reservation = restTemplate.getForObject(""+id, Reservation.class);
    return null;
}
```

}